# Is there an alternative solution to obatin a network diagram visualization?

Tags: sas, sas-visual-analytics

I read in the sas documentation that it isn't allowed to export a network diagram visualization. See links below:
[SAS Limitation](http://support.sas.com/kb/57/957.html)
[SAS export visualization](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/vaug/68648/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p02k9rf7vy6umln1ew6v84w1989r.htm)
Is there another way to accomplish a similar result in SAS? I mean, is there a way to obtain a network visualization as portable output?
Thanks

Comment: Are you only looking for SAS VA solutions or are you open to SAS graphs produced from SAS programming products?

Comment: What portable output format do you want?

Comment: not only VA solutions; html report wolud be the best solution, but other alternative ones wouldn't be minded.